Split vector to chunks
Maybe I am a bit overthinking this one, but I am trying to understand if there is some better way to do the following in C++: having a vector of e.g. 100 objects, split it to 10 different chunks (10 different std::vectors), which are then assigned to attributes of custom structs (e.g. Data) also located in a vector.
Example to make  it more clear:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Point {
public:
    double x, y, z;

    Point(double x_val, double y_val, double z_val) : x(x_val), y(y_val), z(z_val) {}
};

class Data {
public:
    std::vector<Point> trajectory;

    // Constructor
    Data() = default;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> original;

    // Same data - only example
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        original.emplace_back(1.0, 2.0, 3.0); 
    }

    std::vector<Data> all_data;
    size_t chunk_size = 10;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < original.size(); i += chunk_size) {
        Data data;
        auto start = original.begin() + i;
        auto end = (i + chunk_size <= original.size()) ? start + chunk_size : original.end();

        data.trajectory.insert(data.trajectory.end(), start, end);

        all_data.emplace_back(worker);
    }
}

Not sure if there is much else to do here in terms of time complexity, but in terms of memory complexity: is there some way to make sure we are not making unnecessary copies here?
It is never clear to me whether C++ copies or moves due to unclear move definition. I am using only GCC and not aiming towards support of other compilers. C++20 features can be used.
What about reverting this operation, i.e. getting a full vector from chunks stored in attributes?

I assume the last line is supposed to read all_data.emplace_back(data);. Anyway, you cause a copy there. You have to move the data. The only time a move is implied is at the return of a function

And the Point class itself is composed only of primitive types for which copying or moving makes no difference. If it did, you had to use std::make_move_iterator in your insert call, which, btw. can be replaced with an assign(start, end) to make the code a bit shorter

std::ranges::chunk_view C++23 might interest you (and range-v3's version for C++20)

As indicated by @Jarod42, I think the most modern and efficient way to do this is to use std::views::chunk coupled with std::ranges::to from the c++23 standard.
I've checked that GCC already implements this in its latest versions, and all you have to do is change your project's standard to be able to use it.
If migrating to c++23 causes problems in your project, you can also use exactly the same functionality implemented in c++20 in the range-v3 library.
In your code example, it's not clear whether you want to create the Data objects from the chunks or whether they already exist and you just want to fill in the attributes.
I assume from the text of the question that they already exist, but here's an example for each possibility:
Constructing case :
const std::vector original(100, Point(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
const size_t chunk_size = 10u;

std::vector<Data> all_data = original 
    | std::views::chunk(chunk_size) 
    | std::views::transform([](auto &&chunk) {
        Data data;
        data.trajectory = chunk | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
        return data;
    }) 
    | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();

Objects already exisiting case:
const std::vector original(100, Point(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
const size_t chunk_size = 10u;
std::vector<Data> all_data(original.size() / chunk_size);

for (auto &&[data, chunk] :
        std::views::zip(all_data, original | std::views::chunk(chunk_size))) {
    data.trajectory = chunk | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
}

You will need std::views::zip for this case but it's also already implemented by gcc
The most efficient approach is obviously to build Data objects on the fly from chunks and other elements required to construct the Data object.
Demo

Your example doesn't use very much memory, so making copies really isn't an issue. But, if you really want to avoid it, you can either:

use all_data.push_back(std::move(data)); to move data into all_data without copying it.

just get rid of Data data; altogether, and use either all_data.emplace_back().assign(start, end) or maybe all_data.emplace_back(start, end) to avoid creating a vector that has to be moved afterwards.


Either way, you might also consider using all_data.reserve() before entering the loop, to avoid unnecessary copies/moves while the loop is adding vectors to all_data:
size_t numChunks = original.size() / chunk_size;
if (original.size() % chunk_size)
    ++numChunks;

std::vector<Data> all_data;
all_data.reserve(numChunks);

Of course, if you really want to avoid making copies of Points, you could change Data.trajectory to hold Point* pointers to the original vector elements.  Or change original to hold std::shared_ptr<Point> elements that you can then share with all_data.

Well, of course we are talking only about MRE here, otherwise Data also can have other attributes, and number of elements is rather closer to millions than to hundreds :)
